# How to do @OneToMany mapping between two inpedendent tables using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to do @oneToMany relationship between two independent tables. I want to get the count of comments for each post.

```
Select * from post_id, post_msg, count(*) from POST, COMMENTS where post_id = comment_gen_id

POST table
////////////
post_id (PRIMARY KEY)
post_msg (NOT NULL)

COMMENT table
///////////////
Comment_id (PRIMARY KEY)
comment_gen_id 
comment_user
```

Below is my mapping,

```
Class Post{
    @Column(name="POST_ID")
    private int post_id;

    @Column(name="POST_MSG")
    private String post_msg;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="post")
    private Set<Comments> commentsList;
}

class Comments{
    @ManyToOne
    private Post post;

    @Column(name="comment_id")
    private int commentId;


    @Column(name="comment_gen_id")
    private int commentGenId;

    @Column(name="comment_user")
    private String user;
}
```

Here I have no idea how to make (**post_id = comment_gen_id**) using hibernate criteria.

```
Criteria = session.createCriteria(Post.class)
       .createAlias("commentsList", "comments")
       .add(Restriction.eq("post_id", "comments.commentGenId");
```

Now I am not getting any records from this query. Please help me with this what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance!!!!.

Comment: This condition (post_id = comment_gen_id) doesn't make much sense. What is commentGenId supposed to be? Your table definition doesn't match with your entity definition: the comment table lacks the post_id column necessary to map the ManyToOne association between comment and post.

Comment: commentGenId sholud be post_id.

Comment: Then rename the column in the DB to post_id, and remove the commentGenId field from your entity. And then just remove the `.add(Restriction.eq("post_id", "comments.commentGenId")` from your query.

Comment: I can't change the field names as it's an legacy system.

Comment: What do you mean by "field name"? Do you mean the name of the column comment_gen_id in the database? If the ManyToOne with `post` is mapped by the `comment_gen_id` column in the table, then annotate it with `@JoinColumn(name = "comment_gen_id")`.

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "comment_gen_id") in Comment.java?

Comment: Yes. It's the mapping of the ManyToOne with post, as I just said. This is fundamental stuff. You need to read the Hibernate manual.

Comment: Thanks. That's Working. Yes I should read I am new I need to take a look into it.